# Ubuntu doesn't show when restarting MacBook Pro

Tags: dual-boot, reboot, restart, macbook-pro

I've had Ubuntu for a while now, almost two weeks. I used rEFIt as a tool to open Ubuntu when I restart. I decided to delete it. Now I can't open Ubuntu. When I restart my MacBook Pro and press alt/option at start up, I get two disks options, Macintosh HD and Recovery. Viewing Disk Utility in my Mac OS I know that Ubuntu is still there, I want to use it :)

Comment: Why did you uninstall refit? Install refind (updated refit) and you will be able to boot again http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macs normal boot process can't see the ubuntu partition and can't boot to it.  You need to install rEFInd which is a fork of refit and is still supported.

I just followed this guide and had no problems

http://www.howtogeek.com/187410/how-to-install-and-dual-boot-linux-on-a-mac/

Comment: You could also consider installing grub natively. I was able to acheive this by using a refind CD to boot my ubuntu installation, then running boot-repair and allowing it to configure my EFI partition.